# convert non-standard latin characters in a string to standard ones

Tags: python

I'm not sure if "standard" and "non-standard" are the right terms to use, apologies.

I basically have a bunch of names, such as:

```
Agit Işık
Ruşen Ünaydın
Candî Hissên
```

And I want them converted to:

```
agit-isik
rusen-unaydin
candi-hissen
```

I have created the following function that works most of the time, but not always:

```
import unicodedata

def get_name_slug(name):
    formatted_name = name.lower().replace(' ', '-')
    slug =  unicodedata.normalize('NFD', formatted_name).encode('ascii', 'ignore')

    return slug.decode('utf-8')
```

The result of the above function is:

```
agit-isk
rusen-unaydn
candi-hissen
```

Notice how `Agit Işık` and `Ruşen Ünaydın` failed to convert properly.

What am I missing?

Comment: The problem is that `ü` can be decomposed into `u` and `¨`, so it's the diaresis/umlaut that gets ignored during encoding, leaving the `u` intact. (The same applies to `î` and `ê`, separating the underlying vowel from `ˆ`.) `ı`, however, does not decompose into anything. Unicode normalization isn't about replacing non-ASCII characters with ASCII approximations.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_compatibility_characters for more information about when normalization *will* replace one character with another.

Comment: If you want your own transliteration scheme, it's best to define it explicitly using `str.maketrans`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try fixing special cases by hand, something like:

```
def get_name_slug(name):
    formatted_name = name.lower().replace(' ', '-').replace('ı','i')
    slug =  unicodedata.normalize('NFD', formatted_name).encode('ascii', 'ignore')

    return slug.decode('utf-8')
```

Comment: Thank you @rikyeah, that works.